# Getting started with Chebyshev polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I'm getting introduced to a new concept "Chebyshev polynomials". I would like to develop a deeper understanding on Chebyshev polynomials and its properties. I'm clueless how to get started with it. Any references, books shared would help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: ‘Chebyshev Polynomials’ by TJ Rivlin would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thank you for the guide